# ramsey/uuid - validate a name-based hashed has the name that we assign it to the uuid

Tags: slim, uuid, packagist, slim-3

Any reliable uuid package from Packagist that I can download and use it for Slim framework?

Ideally,I would an uuid that I can hash a type, e.g. php, into the string. then i can check if that uuid has 'php'.

**EDIT:**

How can I validate a [name-based hashed](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) has the **name** that we assign it to the uuid?

```
// Generate a version 3 (name-based and hashed with MD5) UUID object
$uuid3 = Uuid::uuid3(Uuid::NAMESPACE_DNS, 'php.net');
$uuid = $uuid3->toString();
```

For instance:

```
if ($uuid3->getName($uuid) === 'php.net') {
// do something
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best UUID package is https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Just use `composer require ramsey/uuid` to install it.

> Ideally,I would an uuid that I can hash a type, e.g. php, into the string. then i can check if that uuid has 'php'.

I don't understand this. UUIDs create a unique string. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

> A universally unique identifier (UUID) is a 128-bit number used to identify information in computer systems. The term globally unique identifier (GUID) is also used.
>
> When generated according to the standard methods, UUIDs are for practical purposes unique, without depending for their uniqueness on a central registration authority or coordination between the parties generating them

Edit.

To answer your new question…

You can't reverse a hash, so you need to hash again and compare.

```php
$uuid = Uuid::uuid3(Uuid::NAMESPACE_DNS, 'php.net')->toString();

$domainFromUser = 'example.com';
$userUuid = Uuid::uuid3(Uuid::NAMESPACE_DNS, $domainFromUser)->toString();

if ($uuid === $userUuid) {
    // user provided the right domain
}
```

Comment: thanks rob, `UUIDs create a unique string` - then what is the advantaces of having  `ramsey/uuid` or any other uuid package than php `uniqid()`?

Comment: uniqid() is just a timestamp iirc and so two servers calling uniqid() at the same time will get the same result.

Comment: `I don't understand this.` please see my edit above.